# SQLite DateTime Comparison With VARCHAR

Tags: wpf, sqlite

I got some problem with SQLite DataTime Filtering.
I used `System.Data.SQLite` in my wpf project.
I can filter using the following sql query.

```
SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE CAST(testDate As date) > CAST('28/09/2015' As date);
```

According to above sql, I get all the dates bigger than 28/09/2015. btw testDate field is Varchar data type in my sqlite table.

When I use the `BETWEEN` clause, I get nothing.

```
SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE CAST(testDate As date) BETWEEN CAST('28/09/2015' as date) AND CAST('10/10/2015' as date);
```

How should I filter date in between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dd/mm/yyyy` is not a valid TimeString in SQLite.
The correct format is `yyyy-mm-dd`.

As reported [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), 
valid TimeStrings in SQLite are:

- YYYY-MM-DD
- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
- YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
- YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
- YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
- HH:MM
- HH:MM:SS
- HH:MM:SS.SSS
- now
- DDDDDDDDDD

And you don't need to cast to... date (which is not an existing data type in SQLite, and it will fall back to TEXT).

Reference on SQLite DataTypes: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Also note that the semicolon (**;**) at the end of queries and commands is completely useless, since SQLite won't concatenate SQL statements.

In the end, your query should really be

```
SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE testDate BETWEEN '2015-09-28' AND '2015-10-10'
```